# How To Explain All data with parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, codeigniter-3

Hi guys i have an issue for displaying  all data where a column with name header_id having same data. but when it displayed, his result
just one row. actually of data with header_id='100002' having 4 rows.Thanks.

Model:

```
function getdtHeaderid($header_id = FALSE) {
             if ($header_id === FALSE)
            {
                $query = $this->db1->get('tbltransactiondtl');
                return $query->result_array();

            }
            $query = $this->db1->get_where('tbltransactiondtl', array('header_id' => $header_id));
            return $query->row_array();
        }
```

Controller:

```
function getdtHeaderid() {
            $header_id = $this->input->post('header_id');
            $data=$this->M_selltransaction->getdtHeaderid($header_id);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

View:

```
     <div class="col-md-6">                                     
        <label for="header_id" class="col-md-4 control-label" style="text-align:left">Transaction No</label>
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label">:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">                                                  
        <div class="input-group input-group-unstyled">
        <input type="text" class="header_id form-control" placeholder="Search" id="header_id" name="header_id"/>
                                                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-search "></i></span>
            </div>
       </div>
 </div>
        <table>
            <td><input type="text" width="10" class="detail_id form-control"
             id="detail_id" name="detail_id[]"   value="<?php $a =
             set_value('detail_id[0]'); echo $a;?>" required ></td>

            <td><input
             type="text" width="10" class="item_code form-control" id="item_code"
             name="item_code[]"   value="<?php $a = set_value('item_code[0]'); echo
             $a;?>" required ></td> 

            <td><input type="text" class="item_name
             form-control" id="item_name" name="item_name[]" value=""
            readonly></td>
    </table>


            <script type="text/javascript">
            function getdHeaderid(header_id){
                var header_id = header_id.val();
                $.ajax({
                        type    : "post",
                        data    : {header_id:header_id},                       
                        url     : "<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/transaction/selltransaction/getdtHeaderid",
                        dataType:"json",
                        cache :false,
                        success: function(data){ 
                        console.log(data);

                             $(".detail_id").val(data.detail_id);
                             $(".item_code").val(data.item_code);
                             $(".item_name").val(data.item_name);


                       }   
                });
             }

                $(document).ready(function() { 
                 $('.header_id').on('keyup change', function() {
                  getdHeaderid($(this)); 
                });
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getdtHeaderid($header_id = FALSE) {
         if ($header_id === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db1->get('tbltransactiondtl');
            return $query->result_array();

        }
        $query = $this->db1->get_where('tbltransactiondtl', array('header_id' => $header_id));
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Here is Your Correct model function you were using **row_array()** instead of **result_array()** thats why getting only one result

Answer (score 0):

update

```
$(".detail_id").val(data.detail_id);
```

$(".item_code").val(data.item_code);
$(".item_name").val(data.item_name);

to

```
$(".detail_id").val(data[0].detail_id);
```

$(".item_code").val(data[0].item_code);
$(".item_name").val(data[0].item_name);

Comment: Madumal  thank you so much for your responses and i am sorry for my late to reply your responses. yesterday  i got an problem solved for this. nice to meet you in the stackoverflow.